# Google Sheets - Formatting data in cell into a date

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am working on a larger data set that has a date related column with data that is not in date form but rather in number form. (ex. instead of 11/02/2024 it's setup as 11022024) I've also included a screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fxZh.png)

I tried a couple of different things such as highlighting the column and clicking on format to change the data into a date but the numbers completely change. See screenshot(this is after highlighting the data above > going to format> Numbers> Date):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGl2A.png)

I've also tried to change the format into custom versions but the numbers still completely change as shown above - I've also tried to enter the DATE formula into a separate column and the numbers still change completely from the original dates.

Has anyone ever encountered this or does anyone know how to fix this problem? The data set is large enough that it would take hours for me to individually update each cell.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,to_date(--regexreplace(Σ&"","(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})","$2/$1/$3")))))
```

[image]

Comment: This was a HUGE help thank you! For some reason it still had some issues with certain dates - for instance in one of the cells the date is 6122017 but it formats into 7/5/18661. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: try replacing the **first** `\d{2}` with `\d{1,2}`